# No "Android Feed" under "Promote" link

Tags: android, facebook

In the campaign set up for a mobile app campaign, the instructions say there should be an "iOS Feed" and an "Android Feed" under the Promote link on the left menu.  I've implemented the SDK in both my Android and iOS app and added both to the app settings but am only seeing "iOS Feed" under Promote.  How come I am not seeing "Android Feed"?

Answer (score 1):

You have to mark "Facebook Login" as enabled (even though you don't need to have it implemented in your app) in order to show the "Android Feed" under the promote link.  We are working to remove this issue soon, but for the time being just mark "Facebook Login" as enabled.